# java.io.FileNotFoundException when file is in folder

Tags: jsf, file-io, jsf-2, filenotfoundexception

I have created project using JF 2.0.

When I run project, I can execute file `xyz.xhtml` by saying `http://localhost:8080/myProject/faces/xyz.xhtml`

However when I put the same in in folder `xyz` and try to execute as `http://localhost:8080/myProject/faces/xyz/xyz.xhtml` I get exception as `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

First few lines of stacktrace are

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException
at org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnection.getInputStream(DirContextURLConnection.java:403)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache._getLastModified(DefaultFaceletCache.java:172)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.access$000(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
```

Can someone point at what I am doing wrong?

### Update 1

File structure I have is

```
+ Web Content
  + WEB-INF
    - web.xml
    - faces-config.xml
  + xyz
    - xyz.xhtml
  - xyz.xhtml
```

Comment: Can you post the code that the stacktrace relates to?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen : I don't have any code. When I put file in directory and use new path I get this error...

Comment: Put your folder structure to analyze the problem and your web.xml configuration for Faces Servlet servlet mapping.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : You meant you need content of web.xml and faces-config.xml file? I don't I need to display that as project is working fine when I don't have folder...

Comment: @FahimParkar I think my answer explains what I coudln't ask in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have a first folder structure like this

```
+ Web Content
  - xyz.xhtml
  + xyz
    - xyz.xhtml
```

And your servlet mapping configuration for the Faces Servlet looks like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This means that the Faces Servlet (the servlet that send the request to the JSF framework) will apply for every page inside the ProjectName/faces/<whatever> (if and only if the pages are under a faces folder structure). If you want to apply the Faces Servlet for every html page in your site, change the configuration to this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

EDIT

I've made a test based in your problem. It should work with no problems. Make sure the project have been built correctly and it has been correctly deployed, if you still have these problems try changing the servlet mapping configuration.

Comment: there is no folder called faces as such... I have directory as mentioned by you...

Comment: Then try the proposed solution by changing the servlet mapping configuration.

Comment: It should work even without changing the servlet-mapping, only possibilities remain are either the OP has placed the file in wrong directory possibly WEB-INF or the app server is not publishing the resources automatically.

Comment: @FahimParkar answer updated. As a last resource, you can contact me via email to solve the problem (note: this will be out of the StackOverflow scope).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `xyz.xhtml`: it is referencing a resource (template? include?) using a relative path, instead of an absolute path - and when you move it down into a directory that reference is no longer valid.